# Socket communication with android devices

Tags: android, database, sockets

Can i interact with a server(android device) from a client(android device) just to query a database located in the server using TCP sockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And Yes and No.
If your device is within wireless network and have own local IP. You can connect to it from client phone if it is in the same network just providing proper IP and Port.
If server phone is located in another wireless network, then Port have to be forwarder using router settings to the server port. Bear in mind that if you will reconnect to wireless network by phone, then IP will be automatically assigned by network infrastructure and it might be changed from previous.

If you want to connect to server phone when it is on 3G network (or similar non wifi), you wont have any specific IP, and it is not static, that way it will be almost impossible to create reliable network. It is more Peer-to-Peer model of network you are looking for.

It is much better if you use Server in the middle as Gateway, that way it will be reliable. The only thing is that you will have to host server and its processes with all traffic and so on.